# Is For...In loop only option to create an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is For-In loop only option to create an object with properties or is there a better approach? I would like to create an object instead of array.

Currently it loop data.Batch using for-in loop and do some total calculation and property mapping.

For example:

```js
let data = {
  Batch: {
    111: { BatchId: 111, Name: "Batch 1", Count2017: 100, Count2018: 100 },
    222: { BatchId: 222, Name: "Batch 2", Count2017: 200, Count2018: 300 }
  }
};

function calculateBatch(batch) {
  mappedObject = {};
  let grandTotal = 0;

  for (const batchId in data.Batch) {
    let total = data.Batch[batchId].Count2017 + data.Batch[batchId].Count2018;

    mappedObject[batchId] = {
      BatchId: batchId,
      Name: data.Batch[batchId].Name,
      Total: total
    };

    grandTotal += total
  }

  return {
      Batch: mappedObject,
      GrandTotal: grandTotal
  }
}

console.log(calculateBatch(data.Batch));
```

Comment: This is the best (fastest) approach, although it would appear your `batch` data structure could be an `Array` instead of `Object` since it doesn't make sense to have _Keys_ if you don't really use them

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please describe it with clear sentences.

Comment: You may want to search for object reduce

Comment: Pfft, there are at least half a dozen ways to create an object.

Comment: What do you define as "better"? If it would be "faster", you have the fastest. If it would be shortest or most *functional programming* style, then there are alternatives.

Comment: **primarily opinion-based:**
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: You forgot to declare `mappedObject` as a local variable with `var` (or `let` or `const`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Object.keys()` to get an array of property names and then `.reduce()` to create the result object:

```
return Object.keys(batch).reduce(function(result, key) {
  let total = batch[key].Count2017 + batch[key].Count2018;
  result.Batch[key] = {
    BatchID: key,
    Name: batch[key].Name,
    Total: total
  };
  result.GrandTotal += total;
  return result;
}, { Batch: {}, GrandTotal: 0 });
```

Whether this is "better" than your posted code is subjective. It's a little shorter; does that make it more readable or maintainable or less? Different people would give different answers.

As to the performance, almost any simple iterative approach will be as fast as another for any practical application. If you have millions of these batches, then nothing is going to make the iteration "fast" in an absolute sense.

Comment: I am not talking about fastest, I am talking about maintainable and easy to read.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back, could you specify that in the question, please? It is currently not saying that. "Better" can mean a lot of things.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back sure, well that's a style matter and you have to take your own preferences into account.

Comment: "easy to read" is a rather subjective measure, I would say. When I was less experienced with computer science in general, easy to read for me was anything I could easily understand while reading. Which was for loops, and mutable variable assignment and reassignment. Today, I find purely functional programming samples easier to read and easier to understand. Funny, that.

Comment: TBH, I don't think `reduce` is shorter, as it usually needs an additional `return` statement. The rest is just different formatting.